# How to Extract a specific div content from a external website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to extract some information from a external website with Jquery .load() method, But this doesn't seem to be working, any thoughts why? I tested on both firefox and chrome.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#div1").load("http://www.weather.com/weather/5-day/CEXX0001 #wx-forecast-container");
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>
<button>Get External Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It will throw an error
**No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource**

Reason is you can not access external domain url through XmlHttpRequest.

Alternative is create server side intermediater that pull data from weather.com and serve to your page using load or ajax method.

Answer (score 1):

You are facing crossdomain policy restrictions. Browser simply won't allow you to load content from external website,
You can try to place crossdomain.xml on weather.com, however you can't